Custom_Widgets button navigation not working
I've been working on a json file code as a way to easily change the displayed chart type in my application when buttons are clicked (for example, clicking on the button named "Donut" will show a donut chart), and a stacked widget will be used to show the charts. Here's what I wrote:
{
    "QStackedWidget":[
        {
            "name":"stackedWidget_2",
            "transitionAnimation":[
                {
                    "slide":[{
                        "active": true,
                        "duration":1000,
                        "direction": "horizontal",
                        "erasingCurve": "Linear"
                    }
                ]
                }
            ],
            "navigation":[{
                "navigationButtons":[
                    {
                        "btn1": "perc",
                        "btn2": "donut",
                        "temp": "temp",
                        "btn4": "line",
                        "btn5": "bar"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }],
    "QCustomSlideMenu": [{
                "name": "left_menu",
                "defaultSize": [{
                    "width": 0,
                    "height": "parent"
                }],
                "collapsedSize": [{
                    "width": 0,
                    "height": "parent"
                }],
                "expandedSize": [{
                    "width": 250,
                    "height": "parent"
                }],
                "toggleButton": [{
                    "buttonName": "menu_btn"
                }],
                "menuTransitionAnimation": [{
                    "animationDuration": 500,
                    "animationEasingCurve": "Linear"
                }]
            }]       
}

Here's the python file where I'm loading the json file:
import os
import sys

import csv
from propiedades import *


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from functools import partial
from Custom_Widgets import *
from Custom_Widgets.QAppSettings import QAppSettings



shadow_elements = { "left_menu","frame_3", "frame_5", "header", "frame_8"}

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self,parent=None):
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
            
            self.setMinimumSize(850,600)
            
            loadJsonStyle(self, self.ui)
            for x in shadow_elements:
                
                effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
                effect.setBlurRadius(18)
                effect.setXOffset(0)
                effect.setYOffset(0)
                effect.setColor(QColor(0,0,0,255))
                getattr(self.ui,x).setGraphicsEffect(effect)
            
            
            self.show()
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


The issue I'm having is that whenever I click on any of the buttons, their respective charts never show up.
I tried promoting the stacked widget to "QCustomQStackedWidget" to see if it fixes the issue but it doesn't. Any advice? I've asked the creator of QT-PyQt-PySide-Custom-Widgets to see they could address the problem but I have gotten no response.

That "custom widgets" module has some interesting concepts in its graphical design. Sadly, it's actually extremely poorly written: the codebase is very convoluted, especially the part dealing with json parsing and property management (the JSonStyles/__init__.py contains some for/if going up to 10 nested levels, which is complete madness IMHO). We've got some questions about it in the past, and, sincerely, we cannot answer any of them (including yours): nobody in their right mind would go through debugging such absurdity. I'm actually surprised the maintainer is still able to manage it.

So, sorry, but I doubt anybody would help you here. You can hope that the maintainer will eventually answer and fix the issue, but, unless they finally decide to do proper refactoring, my suggestion is to keep away from that module anyway. Its whole structure is unstable and unreliable, debugging it would cause headaches just to understand where problems may be (way before finding what actually causes them), and as soon as they're not able to maintain it anymore, you'll be completely lost. If you want to use some of their widgets, study their code, and create your own instead.
